# How do I change format datetime in HTML to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: html, datetime-format

for example I have this HTML code :

```
  <div class="sub_continer">
                            <div class="cell">מתאריך</div>
                            <div class="cell">  
                                <input placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" type="date" id="Creation_date_R2FromId"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Its look like
[image]

I cant find any way to change it to look like dd-mm-yyyy this format

(day on left, month on mid and year to the right)

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `input type=date` you cannot change how the value is displayed.

> The displayed date format will differ from the actual value — **the displayed date is formatted based on the locale of the user's browser**, but the parsed value is always formatted `yyyy-mm-dd`.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#value

If you need a different display, you will have to resort to `input type=text`.